# How to make GraphQL making asynchronus/parralel/concurrently query in Java? (code examples inside)

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

I have project in `java 8` currently.

If i am using only:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphiql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version> <!--5.0.2 http://localhost:8999/graphiql fails to load-->
    </dependency>
```

And have schema like:

```
type Query {
    getAllItems: [TestEntity]
    getItem(dictionaryType: String): TestEntity
    }

    type TestEntity {
    code: String!
    name: String
    description: String
    dictionaryType: String
}
```

1)
And have `resolver` like:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class QueryResolver implements GraphQLQueryResolver {
    @Autowired
    private final DictionaryService dictionaryService;

    public List<TestEntity> getAllItems() {
        return dictionaryService.getAllDictionaryItemsAsStrings();
    }

    public TestEntity getItem(String dictionaryType) {
        return dictionaryService.getDictionaryItemsFirstAsString(dictionaryType);
    }
}
```

If i ask for `two` resources at once:

```
query {
    getAllItems {
        code
        description
    }
        getItem(dictionaryType: "test1") {
        code
        name
        description
    }
}
```

Does `getItem` and `getAllItems` execute `asynchronusly`/`parralel`/`concurrently` or the task is executed one by one?

2)
If we change our code with the same schema, but withous implementing `resolvers, so like that:

```
@RestController
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class GraphqlController {
    private final DictionaryService dictionaryService;

    private DataFetcher<List<TestEntity>> allDictionaryItemsFetcher;
    private DataFetcher<TestEntity> dictionaryItemFetcher;

    @Value("classpath:test-resolvers.graphqls")
    private Resource schemaResource;
    private GraphQL graphQL;

    @PostConstruct
    private void loadSchema() throws IOException {
        File schemaFile = schemaResource.getFile();
        TypeDefinitionRegistry registry = new SchemaParser().parse(schemaFile);
        RuntimeWiring wiring = buildWiring();
        GraphQLSchema schema = new SchemaGenerator().makeExecutableSchema(registry, wiring);
        graphQL = GraphQL.newGraphQL(schema).build();
    }

    private void initializeFetchers() {
        allDictionaryItemsFetcher = dataFetchingEnvironment -> dictionaryService.getAllDictionaryItemsAsStrings();
        dictionaryItemFetcher = dataFetchingEnvironment ->
                dictionaryService.getDictionaryItemsFirstAsString(dataFetchingEnvironment.getArgument("dictionaryType"));
    }

    private RuntimeWiring buildWiring() {
        initializeFetchers();
        return RuntimeWiring.newRuntimeWiring()
                .type("Query", typeWriting -> typeWriting
                        .dataFetcher("getAllItems", allDictionaryItemsFetcher)
                        .dataFetcher("getItem", dictionaryItemFetcher)
                )
                .build();
    }

    @PostMapping("graphql")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getResource(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> request) {
        ExecutionResult result;
            String query = request.get("query").toString();
            Map<String, Object> variables = (Map<String, Object>) (request).get("variables");

            ExecutionInput input = ExecutionInput.newExecutionInput()
                    .query(query)
                    .variables(variables)
                    .context(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication())
                    .build();

            result = graphQL.execute(input);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

It probably does not run asychnously, cause we need to use for example `CompletableFuture`. I am not sure how to change that code to `asynchronous`/`concurrently`/`parralel` if someone too would should what change i have to made to make it that way i would be glad. 
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

In example `2)` i could write something like:

```
@PostMapping("graphql")
public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>> handleReqDefResult(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> request) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>> output = new DeferredResult<>();

    CompletableFuture<ExecutionResult>  result;
    String query = request.get("query").toString();
    Map<String, Object> variables = (Map<String, Object>) (request).get("variables");

    ExecutionInput input = ExecutionInput.newExecutionInput()
            .query(query)
            .variables(variables)
            .context(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication())
            .build();

    result = graphQL.executeAsync(input);
    output.setResult(ResponseEntity.ok(result.get()));
    return output;
}
```

Comment: `CompletableFuture` isn't the only way to make something async.  In particular, the actual mechanism may be hidden from you (ie, not needing to explicitly wait for/check whether a future has completed yet) - take, for instance, Spring WebFlux's `Mono` and related types, where you write continuations, and the framework itself (usually) handles asynchonicity.  That said, using `ResponseEntity` that way is most likely going to make it synchronous, but I'm at a loss as to _why_ you'd try to write the code that way.

Comment: Above i am using `java 8` (the project is not new) - so i can not use `mono`/`flux`. What can i use there if not `ResponseEntity`  (that exist in `java 8, and i think i would skip `RxJava` cause it is not used in the project)? What do you mean by `why you'd try to write the code that way` ? I am trying to make this more asynchronous, see: https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/pull/590

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse And in example `1)` i want to determine if it is `asynchronus` or not ? Cause i am not sure - how the library `under-hood` works.

Comment: You've got a few different problems.  1) With respect to putting in two different queries into the request, you actually want to know if they run _concurrently_, which is orthogonal to asynchronicity.  It looks like graphQL intends for that to be possible, so I assume the implementation can do so, but that isn't something you can actually rely on.  2) My problem with your current implementation idea is that you're resolving the query yourself - you've created an intermediate client.  This has increased your maintenance surface area, among other things.

Comment: 3) If you want async execution, you need to be using framework/language support for it.  That's not `ResponseEntity`.  It looks like it might be covered by `StreamingResponseBody`... however, you're going to be better off moving to Java 11, getting the [graphql webflux artifact](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-spring#artifacts), and letting the frameworks handle all this.  Why?  Because just returning `CompletableFuture` doesn't make things async - in particular, you want whatever internal I/O you do to be woven into the async flow.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse thank you very much for comments.
 ad 1) You may be right - that more accurate words would be `concurrently` or even `parallel` - i will fix the question. I do not understand why you wrote `but that isn't something you can actually rely on.` ?
Ad 2) I did it in example 2) - but it has also advantages. And i know many things how this does work - as i don't know in example 1) Cause there code is `under-hood`

Ad 3) I also read about: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-deferred-result
in regards to changing `ResponseEntity`

Comment: 1) Just because a piece of code _can_ run concurrently, doesn't mean that it will (sometimes sequential is faster, or the other thread might be delayed, or...).  Generally, the answer is only interesting if monitoring shows a combined request is taking a lot of wall-clock time.  2)  The point of using a framework/library is so that you **don't** have to know what code does internally, and only concentrate on the interesting/novel stuff.

Comment: 3) While that gets the graphql stuff off the main HTTP thread, you're still writing an inner client, which should generally be avoided.  In particular, you would be better served if any I/O your graphql code does is also async, and part of the same context.  Which is why, again, I'm recommending updating the project and letting the framework handle it.  Note, too, that doing this doesn't necessarily solve your concurrency question (you're still relying on the framework to handle it).  4) What, if any, is the real-world problem you're actually trying to solve here?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Thanks for advices. Ad 4) I am just making `reasearch` of `GraphQL`Ad 1) That's interesting. I want to know is `GraphQL` trying to do many stuff at once (like asking for two resources by query at once) - and i want to know too does it in example 1/2? There's also two option for executing tasks (see updated question) one is `executeAsync` another one is `execute` - i wonder which are default by the framework (in example 1). I am not sure where to find info on that - maybe i should make some debbuging in this library to find out ? But maybe there is an easier option to find out.

Comment: Ad 2) That is true - but i am making presentation about `GraphQL` and i want to know how does it work `underhood`. 
Ad 3) Yes, so you reccommend code like in example 1). Still i want to be sure does `GraphQL` in example 1) execute code `asynchronusly/parrallel/concurrently` or not? 
If  not then maybe i can optimize it somehow like in example 2) - that's my reasoning.

Ad 1) I think that `GraphQL` does have some `default` method in `example 1)` It does not decide whether pick `sync`/`async` method per `scenario`.I think maybe you are reffering how `CPU` works under-hood?Thanks for comments